# SQL Query - Sum of Order tha Contain an Item

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I am surprised I have not been able to find a solution to this.  We have a table

```
ORDER #  |  PRODUCT ID  |  PRICE
   1     |     1        |   1.00
   1     |     2        |   2.00
   2     |     3        |   3.00
   2     |     4        |   4.00
   3     |     1        |   5.00
   3     |     4        |   6.00
```

We want to capture the sum of the revenues of all orders which included productID=1.  The result in this example should be 1+2+5+6 = 14

What is the best way to achieve this?

Currently, best solution I have is to run two queries.
1 - `SELECT orderID FROM table WHERE prodID=$prodID`

2 - `SELECT price FROM table WHERE orderID=[result of the above]`

This has worked, but would strongly prefer to have a single query.

Comment: Why would you need a join?
And please try to add what you have tested.

Comment: Sorry, had the join bc. it is part of a larger system.  But, correct not needed here.  Added what we have running so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select sum(price) as total_price
from orders
where prod_order in
       (select prod_order
       from orders
       where product_id = 1)
```

Check [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29bf4/3) to confirm the result.

Comment: Thanks!  Similar to some of the other responses, but extra points for the SQLFiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that gives the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT OrderNum, SUM(PRICE) as TotalPrice
FROM MyTable AS M
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 -- Include only orders that contain product 1
              FROM MyTable AS M2 
              WHERE M2.OrderNum=M.OrderNum AND M2.ProductId=1)
GROUP BY OrderNum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(price) as total_price where product_id=[enter here id];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(t1.price) FROM tableName t1 WHERE 
t1.orderId IN (SELECT t2.orderId FROM tableName t2 WHERE 
                t2.productId=productIdYouWant)
```

If you need more informations on how this work, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested select. The inner select should give you the total order value;

```
select order, sum(price) as totalvalue from table group by order
```

Now you need to select the orders which have a product id of 1, and sum the order price;

```
select sum(totalvalue) from (
  select order, sum(price) as totalvalue from table group by order
) where order in (
  select order from table where productid = 1
)
```